# seleccionar las alternativas correctas en un selec multiple con ajax

Tags: ajax, select

buen día.
Si alguien me podria ayudar con los siguiente:

Quiero que me seleccione las alternativas correctas en un select multiple comparando los datos que tengo en el blade laravel con datos que me trae de backend utilizando AJAX.

a la izquierda estan los datos que tengo en mi blade laravel y a la derecha los datos como me muestra del backen utilizando AJAX

[image: DATOS BLADE Y AJAX]

Este es mi código en el blade.

```
                    <div class="form-group col-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                        <label class="small" for="idioma_pagina">Idioma Página: </label>
                        <select name="idioma_pagina[]" id="idioma_pagina" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="Select a Lenguages" class="form-control">
                            <option value="">Seleccionar</option>
                            <option value="English">English</option>
                            <option value="Spanish">Spanish</option>
                            <option value="Russian">Russian</option>
                            <option value="German">German</option>
                            <option value="French">French</option>
                            <option value="Italian">Italian</option>
                            <option value="Other languages">Other languages</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
```

Y este es mi codigo con el cual intento traer los datos por ajax. debo aclarar que en la base de datos lo guardé como un array, ya logré creo recorrer el array con Ajax, pero no se como agregar y comparar en el select multiple y que igual me muestre toda la lista y ademas que ya esten seleccionados los que son iguales a los datos traidos desde la base de datos.

```
    $('#idioma_pagina').select2({
        theme: 'bootstrap4',
        placeholder: "Select a Lenguages"
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.edit', function () {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        
        $.ajax({
            url: "/admin/admin/" + id + "/edit",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (html) {
                let array_idioma_pagina = JSON.parse(html.data.idioma_pagina);

                $(array_idioma_pagina).each(function(indice_2, valor_2){
                    let valor_array_idioma_pagina = valor_2;
                    console.log(valor_array_idioma_pagina);
                })
            },
        })
    });
```

Comment: Trata de ser mas claro con lo que deseas lograr

Answer (score 0):

Es simple, dentro de each que tienes luego de hacer la petición AJAX debes buscar cada opción por su valor y añadirle el atributo selected con attr().

```
 $(array_idioma_pagina).each(function(indice_2, valor_2){
         let valor_array_idioma_pagina = valor_2;

         $('#idioma_pagina option[value="' + valor_array_idioma_pagina +'"]').attr("selected","selected");
  })
```

Comment: Muy agradecido, funciono perfecto...